# login page php code not working on cpanel blank page comes after succefull login

Tags: php, xampp, cpanel

The code is working perfectly on localhost xampp server but not working on Cpanel I think sesion_start command not working. If i login using wrong password then it shows an error its mean php code in LoinPage.php 
wroks but when i enter correct username and password it will show blank page instead of taking me to AdminDashboard.php
LoginPage.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>


    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Seza Admin Login</title>



          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loginStyle.css">




    </head>

    <body>


     <?php  include("connection.php");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $msg=null;



            if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=='ok')
            {
            $username =$_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $selectuser = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from admins where USERNAME='".$username."' and PASSWORD ='".$password."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $no_users = mysqli_num_rows($selectuser);
            if($no_users>0)
                {
                    $fetch_user = mysqli_fetch_array($selectuser);
                    $_SESSION['adminid']= $fetch_user['AID'];

                    alert("success");
                    header("location:AdminDashboard.php");

                }
                else{
                    $msg = "The username or password is invalid";
                }
            }
            else{
                if(isset($_POST['login']) && $_POST['login']=='ok')
                {
                echo"invalid";  
                }
            }


         ?>
        <div class="site_wrapper">




      <form  method="post" id="additem-form" >
      <input type="hidden" id="login" name="login" value="ok" />
        <div class="login">

            <div class="login-screen">
                <div class="app-title">
                    <h1>SezaPharma</h1>
                    <h3>ADMIN LOGIN</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username">
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
                    <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" type="submit" value="login" >login</button>
                    <a class="login-link" onClick="alertRset()" href="">Lost ? Reset your password?</a>

                      <div style="color:#FF0004">
                    <?php 
                    if(isset($msg) && $msg!="")
                    { ?>
                        <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo $msg; ?></div> 

                         <?php }

        ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </form>


      <script>
    function alertRset() {
        var txt;
        if (confirm("It will Reset username and password to default.") == true) {
            window.close();
             window.open("resetadmin.php");
        } else {
            txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
    }
    </script>`enter code here`
    </body>
    </html>
```

AdminDashboard.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php   include("connection.php");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

      if (isset($_SESSION['adminid'])) { 

?>

<div class="dashboard">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">All Products</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Add New Product</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Setting</button>
  <a href="logout.php" ><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')" >Loggout</button></a>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent" style="overflow:auto">


  <div class="site_wrapper" >




<div class="clearfix margin_top10"></div>


<div class="works01"  >

<div class="container"  >



    <div id="grid-container" class="cbp-l-grid-fullWidth"  style="overflow:visible;">


     <?php


    $select_post=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from products ORDER BY PID desc") or die(mysqli_error());

    while($post=mysqli_fetch_array($select_post))
    {

    ?>

        <div class="cbp-item <?php echo $post['PTYPE'];?>">
            <div class="cbp-caption">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img style="width:100%; height:200px;" src="UploadedImage/<?php echo $post['PIMAGELOC'];?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <h3><?php echo $post['PNAME'];?></h3>
                            <br />
                            <a href="#" class="cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft">Edit</a>
                            <a href="delete_product.php?PID=<?php echo $post['PID']; ?>" class="cbp-l-caption-buttonLeft" data-title="Looking Publishing <br>reasonable always">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end item -->

        <?php
        }

    ?>




    </div>



</div>
</div><!-- end works section -->













<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a><!-- end scroll to top of the page-->



</div>

</div>
<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
<form action="add_item.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="additem-form" name="additem-form">

  <div class="contactcontainer">
  <header>
    <h1>Add new Product</h1>
  </header>
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
<td  colspan="2">
    <input style="width:74%" placeholder="Product Name" type="text" id="pname" name="pname">
   </td>
   </tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
        <select class="select"   style=" width:74%;"  name="cat" id="cat">
        <option value="Category" selected="selected">Product Category</option>
                <option value="livestock" > livestock Products</option>
                <option value="Poultry">Poultry Products</option>

          </select>  
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td colspan="2" >
          <div style="border:dashed;  width:75%;" align="center">
          <h4>Choose Product Picture</h4>
           <input type="file" id="pimage" name="pimage" class="input-file" title="upload Photo / video"  />
           </div>
           </td>
           </tr>

           <tr>   
         <td>
         <select  class="select" style=" width:55%;" id="ptype" name="ptype">
                <option value="Type">Product Type</option>
                <option value="Injections">Injections</option>
                <option value="Anthilmentics">Anthilmentics</option>
                <option value="Natural">Natural Products</option>
              </select>
              </td>
              <td>
              <select class="select" id="availability"  style=" width:55%;"  name="availability">
                <option value="Availability">Availability</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no">No</option>
              </select>
              </td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <input style="width:74%" class="email" placeholder="Full Farmula with quantity" type="text" id="pfarmula" name="pfarmula">
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <textarea style="width:74%" placeholder="Product Description" id="pdesc" name="pdesc"></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" >
<div style="width:74%" align="center">
  <footer>
    <button style="width:20%" id="addbtn" name="addbtn" >Add</button>
  </footer>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</form>

</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</div> <!--end of tabs-->


<script>


 function validateForm()
    {
    var a=document.forms["additem-form"]["availability"].value;
    var b=document.forms["additem-form"]["pname"].value;
    var c=document.forms["additem-form"]["cat"].value;
    var d=document.forms["additem-form"]["ptype"].value;

    if (a=="Availability" || b=="" || c=="Category" || d=="Type")
      {
      alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
      return false;
      }
    }



function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>



<!-- ######### JS FILES ######### -->
<!-- get jQuery used for the theme -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/universal/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/style-switcher/styleselector.js"></script>
<script src="js/animations/js/animations.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/mainmenu/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/mainmenu/customeUI.js"></script> 
<script src="js/scrolltotop/totop.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/sticky.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mainmenu/modernizr.custom.75180.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cubeportfolio/main31.js"></script>

      <?php } else{ echo " You mus Loggedin to acces this page"; }   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

 session_start();
 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username","password", "sezaphar_sezapharmadb") or die($conn->connect_error);

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're mixing JavaScript (alert) with PHP.  Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. Header is not going to work if you've sent any thing to the client before that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in the code.

You need to **echo** the **alert("success")** before **header("location:AdminDashboard.php");** in **LoginPage.php**

Here's the code:

```
echo "<script>alert('success');</script>";
```

Comment: I have changed it as you said but still its not taking me to AdminDashboard.php.

Comment: alert will not work with header. you need to use javascript to redirect like window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

Comment: i have removed alert line but header is not working still should i implement header with JS now?

Comment: NO it stops loading and a blank page comes.

Comment: you need to start session on the first line of the page.

Comment: i remove session_start from connection.php and wrote just after <!DocTpe html> on loginPage.php and AdminDashboard.php both but still no effect .

Comment: you have to write it before <!DOCTYPE> and anything else.

Comment: i wrote sassion_start before everything as you said but still same  problem. i think its a header() problem because i wrote header on top of php code and it is still not redirecting.

Comment: can you give me JS code of redirecting to other page in php.

Comment: Muhammad Furqan Ul Haq thank you for your support . it was redirect problem header() was not working i implement redirevt in JS an it is working now :)

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery) for redirect in javascript

Comment: Ok that's great.